# jQuery Mobile and PHP Login SESSION

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, session, jquery-mobile

ive been using this login script https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal on my website. It works really great when im not using jquery mobile. When i enable it, it seems like php session, created by the login script, is dead. For example: All login protected pages, has this code on the top of the page:

```
require_once("config/db.php");

require_once("classes/Login.php");

$login = new Login();
```

Whenever i try to back to the last page or even go to a diferent link, the session is not working anymore.

Here is my full main.php code:

```
<?php

require_once("config/db.php");


require_once("classes/Login.php");



$login = new Login();
?>

<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Personal</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0;" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.min.js"></script>



            <script src="libraries/RGraph.common.core.js" ></script>
            <script src="libraries/RGraph.bar.js" ></script>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script>
         function error(text) {
         var n = noty({
                text        : text,
                type        : 'error',
                dismissQueue: true,
                layout      : 'bottomCenter',
                theme       : 'defaultTheme',
                maxVisible  : 5
            });
        }
        function ok(text) {
         var n = noty({
                text        : text,
                type        : 'success',
                dismissQueue: true,
                layout      : 'bottomCenter',
                theme       : 'defaultTheme',
                maxVisible  : 5
            });
        }


        </script>

        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>
<body> 
<div data-role="page" class="page contact-form">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="login.php" data-icon="arrow-l" data-direction="reverse">Voltar</a>
            <a href="index.php" data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div><!--/header-->
        <div color-bar>
            <div data-role="content" align="center" id="logina">
                <!--<h3><em>Faca o login</em></h3>
                    <p>Aqui, voce acessara sua pagina exclusiva.</p>-->
                    <a href="#"><img src='img/logo2.png' alt="portfolio image" /></a>
                    <hr />
                    <div id="contact-form-wrapper">
                    <div data-role="content">
                        <?php

                        echo $_SESSION['user_login_status'];
                        if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {


                            if (isset($_GET["planilha"])){
                                include("views/planilha.php");
                                die();
                            }
                            if (isset($_GET["fichas"])){
                                include("views/fichas.php");
                                die();
                            }
                            if (isset($_GET["progresso"])){
                                include("progresso.php");
                                die();
                            }
                            if (isset($_GET["setexe"])){
                                include("views/setexe.php");
                                die();
                            }
                            if (isset($_GET["addficha"])){
                                include("views/addficha.php");
                                die();
                            }
                            if (isset($_GET["editficha"])){
                                include("views/editficha.php");
                                die();
                            }
                            if (isset($_GET["addficha2"])){
                                include("views/addficha2.php");
                                die();
                            }
                            include("views/logged_in.php");

                        }






                        else {

                                include("views/loginsub.php");
                        }

                        ?>
                </div>
                </div>
```

As you can see, i have a main page the shows the page that i want according to the url parameter. When im not including jquery mobile script, it works nicely. But when its enabled, the login when im navigating thought the website doesn't work well. it seems like the php code to create a new login is not executed whenever i change pages. Ive already disabled ajax navigation, but it keeps bugging.

Someone can help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How/where is `$_SESSION['user_login_status']` being set/defined?

Comment: on classes/Login.php. Where all login code is managed

Comment: If like you say jQuery mobile is at fault, comment out related lines of code one at a time, you will find the bug. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything also.

Comment: i will try that. i dont think its a bug, only some problem with cached data maybe.

Comment: You may have to use `rel="external"` for your `href`'s, it's happened to me before; try that. jQuery Mobile requires that for external pages which could be the case here.

Comment: It doesnt work. And all links are for the same host

Comment: The weird thing is that it only happens sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

In the Login class' `__construct()` function, you'll find `session_start()` --- that must be called on all pages that are going to use the `$_SESSION` variable.

So, on your pages that are not access-controlled, you'll need to throw in `session_start()`

To prove this, why don't you try throwing in blocks like this:

```
if(! session_id() ) {
 echo "No session! Starting, now."; session_start(); 
} else { 
echo session_id(); 
}
```

Comment: but all pages the im accessing is under main.php. When jquery mobile is not enabled, it works great

Comment: There is literally no way for jQuery to interfere with sessions. Not possible in any way shape or form. (Unless, of course, there was something tampering with the PHPSESSID cookie - which is not likely.)

Comment: Its happening. I think the problem is because of this cacheing thing of jQuery Mobile. When i disable it, everything is perfect.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, though. Unless you're saying that jQuery mobile has cached the page without the SESSION on it... but that should be a relatively trivial thing to disable..

Comment: i think thats is the problem. The session id is ok, but when i try to grab $_SESSION['user_login_status'], i get nothing

Comment: try throwing in the code i added in the answer. if it echo's nothing, then you know you have a caching problem...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60351/discussion-between-lucca-zenobio-and-rm-vanda).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `session_start()` on the top of every php file. Every file that is using sessions need to call `session_start()`. That's the common mistaked when dealing with sessions.

Comment: even if im using only 1 php file that shows other ones according to url parameters? Its already on this main one